# Laravel e Github

Tags: php, laravel, github, variáveis-de-ambiente

Boa tarde,
Estou atualmente fazendo um curso e estou na matéria de rotas no curso de laravel, estou acompanhando as aulas perfeitamente. Fiz as instalações de todos os requisitos que estão na aula, como xampp, npm, composer etc. Fiz o meu primeiro projeto local normalmente, fiz igualmente nas vídeos aulas, e tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Porém, eu trabalho com Github durante as minhas aulas, pelo fato de futuramente consultar meus códigos facilmente e pela organização. A questão é o seguinte, quando eu envio o projeto para o Git, e faço o `git clone` novamente em outro terminal, eu verifiquei que o arquivo .env não está vindo novamente, isso se deve pelo fato do arquivo `.gitignore` ignorar o mesmo.

A dúvida é, essa é a forma correta de se versionar um projeto em laravel usando git? Ignorando o .env e caso eu venha precisar trabalhar novamente no projeto, criar um arquivo .env se baseando no .env.example e preenchendo as chaves?

Detalhe, como eu faço esse processo de criar um arquivo .env baseado no .env.examples? Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

> A dúvida é, essa é a forma correta de se versionar um projeto em laravel usando git? Ignorando o .env e caso eu venha precisar trabalhar novamente no projeto, criar um arquivo .env se baseando no .env.example e preenchendo as chaves?

Sim, é o correto. O  arquivo `.env` no Laravel tem como objetivo definir configurações *locais*, para seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

É muito comum você não adicionar ao repositório arquivos que tenham a ver com definições de uma máquina local ou arquivos de dependência externa do projeto.

Quando o arquivo `.env` não está presente, o laravel usará as configurações presentes em `config`.

Pra você entender melhor, o Laravel verifica se o arquivo `.env` existe. Se existe, na chamada da função `env('VALOR', 'valor em produção')`, o Laravel pegará o valor da chave `VALOR` presente do seu `.env`. Se não existir, ele usará o parâmetro `"valor em produção"`.

O `.gitignore` deve ser usado no `.env` sim.

Para você ter uma ideia, eu já tive que trabalhar aqui na empresa com mais dois programadores comigo. Cada um tinha um banco de dados com definições diferentes, senhas diferentes. Quando cometíamos o erro de deixar o `.env` no repositório GIT, toda vez que uma atualização era enviada, os dados do `.env` eram sobrescritos e o programador que recebeu as atualizações tinha o retrabalho de atualizar o arquivo com as configurações certas.

Então, é correto que o `.env` seja ignorado.

> Detalhe, como eu faço esse processo de criar um arquivo .env baseado no .env.examples? Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu não sei se entendi muito bem a pergunta. É só você copiar o arquivo `.env.example` e salvá-lo como `.env` na sua máquina.

O trabalho de configurá-lo será uma vez só, se você ignorá-lo no GIT através do `.gitignore`

**Adendo**

Para se ter uma ideia do que falei sobre certos arquivos que devem ser ignorados, eu costumo ignorar arquivos como `projeto.sublime-project`, uma vez que é um arquivo de configuração do Sublime Text, e o outro programador que vai me ajudar no desenvolvimento pode usar o Visual Studio Code, por exemplo.