# Laravel problema com php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, github, artisan

Estou acompanhando uma aula de Laravel 5.6, e durante a aula, criei o projeto em laravel, já com todas as ferramentas instaladas. NPM, Composer, Xampp etc.

Então rodei o comando:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projeto
```

Fiz todo procedimento da aula, e testei o projeto usando o servidor web com o comando:

```
php artisan serve
```

Entrei no projeto e deu tudo certo. Logo depois, fiz o `git push`, versionando o meu projeto. Essa aula foi assistida e testada em casa.

No dia seguinte, queria continuar a aula da onde eu parei, porém, do meu trabalho, e não mais de casa.

Fiz o `git clone`, e tentei iniciar o projeto novamente com o comando:

```
php artisan serve
```

E me apresentou o erro:

> PHP Warning: require(C:\Users\mazola\Downloads\Udemy-Laravel-Rotas/vendor/autol oad.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\mazola\Do wnloads\Udemy-Laravel-Rotas\artisan on line 18
>
> Warning: require(C:\Users\mazola\Downloads\Udemy-Laravel-Rotas/vendor/autoload.p hp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\mazola\Downloa ds\Udemy-Laravel-Rotas\artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\mazola\Downloads\ Udemy-Laravel-Rotas/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C :\Users\mazola\Downloads\Udemy-Laravel-Rotas\artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\mazola\Downloads\Udemy -Laravel-Rotas/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Use rs\mazola\Downloads\Udemy-Laravel-Rotas\artisan on line 18

Não satisfeito, fiz diversas pesquisas, e acabei achando algumas "soluções"

Uma delas foi rodar o comando:

```
composer update
```

Rodei, e dei novamente o `php artisan serve`. E fui testar no navegador acessando `localhost:8000`

Dessa vez acessou, e iniciou o servidor, porém, quando acessei a página me apresentou uma página de erro:

> 500 Whoops, something went wrong on our servers.

Vale salientar que após eu subir o projeto no git e fazer o clone novamente, o arquivo `.env` não estava mais disponível, somente o `.env.examples`.

Então, entrei no arquivo `.env.examples` e "salvei como" nomeando o mesmo para `.env`, e tentei dar o start novamente, e acabou entrando sem problemas, nas rotas que eu já tinha configurado em aula, sem nenhum erro.

Não sei qual procedimento fazer para dar o start no projeto da forma correta e padronizada, esse procedimento que eu fiz para dar certo é o padrão usado no mercado?

Comment: Você precisa fazer o `composer install` para instalar as dependências. O `composer update` irá atualizar as dependências, o que pode quebrar o seu código. O arquivo [`.env`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339686/laravel-e-github), por padrão, é ignorado pelo git

Comment: Fiz o composer install, e ainda assim permaneceu o erro, após dar o start do projeto :
"500 Whoops, something went wrong on our servers"

Como resolver esse problema, sem ter que abrir o .env.examples e salvar como .env, tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você realizou o comando `php artisan key:generate`?

Answer (score -3):

Defina o que é esse "padrão usado no mercado".
Geralmente para ter o Laravel em sua máquina,checar se o composer esta instalado feito isso aí sim dá o comando para startar o projeto com o framework. 
Fique atento ao clonar projetos,verifique se algum arquivo está faltando ou há um problema de versionamento

Caso necessite de mais detalhes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation